# How to convert std::array to a point?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I want to build a template function to convert std::array to a general point which has a constructor accepting its coordinate arguments.

```
template<typename PointT, size_t N>
PointT to(std::array<double, N> const& a)
{
    return PointT(a[0], a[1], ...); // How to expand a?
}
```

My question is: is there a way to expand the array `a`?

Comment: *"My question is: is there a way to expand the array a?"* Yes, but it is ugly. Can't you pass a pair of iterators to the `PointT` constructor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
template <typename PointT, std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
PointT to(std::array<double, N> const& a, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return PointT(a[Is]...);
}

template <typename PointT, std::size_t N>
PointT to(std::array<double, N> const& a)
{
    return to<PointT>(a, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61b71a45600b452b)

---

**Note**: `index_sequence`/`integer_sequence` utilities are available starting from C++14. Since the question is tagged as `C++11`, the demo code from this answer exploits the following implementation:

```
namespace std
{
    template <std::size_t... Is>
    struct index_sequence {};

    template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
    struct make_index_sequence_h : make_index_sequence_h<N - 1, N - 1, Is...> {};

    template <std::size_t... Is>
    struct make_index_sequence_h<0, Is...>
    {
        using type = index_sequence<Is...>;
    };

    template <std::size_t N>
    using make_index_sequence = typename make_index_sequence_h<N>::type;
}
```

Comment: The demo does undefined behaviour by introducing new symbols into `std` ;)